# Hibernate - Auto or Manual ID - On cluster environment

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, identity

I have an situation where I need to save a hibernate object, but I am not sure whether an ID would be assigned by calling app (using special logic with in a range - unique) or not.

If the ID is not assigned, I need hibernate to generate an ID higher than the possible ID range which the app would input (i know the range). Else should go with what using app inputs.

I am working on MySQL - checking to see if I can custom generator like below

```
public class MyDOIdGenerator extends IdentityGenerator{

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        if ((((MyDO) obj).getId()) == null) {
            Serializable id = super.generate(session, obj) ;
            return id;
        } else {
            return ((MyDO) obj).getId();

        }
    }
}
```

But my problem is, I dont know how the super.generate would behave in a clustered environment.  Would it maintain the ID synchronization across servers? How do I specify the number to start from? (Because I need to exclude the app using id range when having hibernate generate it)

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the DB, set your sequence to start with a specific number  (beginning of the range you mentioned) and then use something like this for your ID annotation, it will ensure hibernate will use the next ID in the sequence and you won't have to worry about clustered/non-clustered environment issue:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem are two here 1- MySQL doesnt support squences 2. My DO object can be either filled with a pre-defined ID (continued data migration & syc through API calls from a different system for around a month - these calls come with an id which is there in the source system). Normal API calls which doesn't come with an ID, the system should recognize that and assign an id appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented this using a table in database as below

```
package com.yahoo.mb.do;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator;

import com.yahoo.sm.ads.common.log.Logger;

public class MyDOGenerator extends IdentityGenerator{

private static final Class clazz = MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass();
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(clazz);

private static String selectQuery = "SELECT nextval FROM identity_value WHERE name='MY_DO' FOR UPDATE";
private static String updateQuery = "UPDATE identity_value SET nextval=?, last_updated=? WHERE name='MY_DO'";

@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
    if ((((MyDO) obj).getId()) == null) {

        Connection connection = session.connection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement selectStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
            PreparedStatement updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);

            logger.info(clazz, "generate", "Generating nextval");
            ResultSet rs = selectStatement.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                Long id = rs.getLong("nextval");
                logger.info(clazz, "generate", "Generated nextval: " + id);
                updateStatement.setLong(1, id+1);
                updateStatement.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));

                logger.info(clazz, "generate", "Updating nextval: " + id);
                updateStatement.executeUpdate();
                return id;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(clazz, "generate", "Error generating ID" + e);
            throw new HibernateException("Unable to generate MyDO id value");
        }
        return null;
    } else {
        return ((MyDO) obj).getId();

    }
}
}
```